# Магический блок кода в Stack Overflow

Tags: обсуждение, подсветка-синтаксиса

Заметил вот такую вещь. Если написать любой код в SO к примеру...

```cs
int a = 3;
int b = 5;

a = a + b;
b = a - b;
a = a - b;

Console.WriteLine($"{a}/{b}");
```

...затем выделить код в блоке и копировать...

> [image]

...то получаем особый блок кода. И в чём особенность?
Например Gmail принимает это как код а не как текст изменяя не только шрифт но ещё и цвет:

> [image]

Так же реагирует и ВКонтакте:

> [image]

...и некоторые другие сайты.

---

Просто сколько я бы не пробовал с помощью тегов создать что-то подобное, у меня не получилось. Вот очень хочется узнать рецепт магического кода. ։-)

Comment: Возможно, этот вопрос, стоит перенести на основной сайт, поскольку он связан с программированием.

Comment: @mymedia я подумал об это но с какими тегами?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

В данном случае магический скорее не блок кода, а то, как обрабатывается событие вставки на указанных сайтах.

При получении данных из clipboard можно указать, что хочешь получать html, в этом случае если копировался html, содержимое может обработано как html, включая скопированные inline-стили.

Например:

```js
document.addEventListener('paste', ({
  clipboardData
}) => {
  var htmlString = clipboardData.getData('text/html');

  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var dom = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, 'text/html');

  [...dom.body.children].reduce((acc, el) => (acc.appendChild(el), acc), document.body);
});
```

Comment: Вот это да. Буду знать))